# navigation drawer как отодвинуть месте с активити

Tags: android

[image: как сделать вот такое Navigation Drawer]

Подскажите как реализовать этот  Navigation Drawer

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6239

Answer (score 1):

xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        tools:openDrawer="start">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ActivityLayout">

        </RelativeLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/header_menu_drawer"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer_items" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

java

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                                this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.abc_action_bar_home_description, R.string.abc_action_bar_home_description) {
                            @Override
                            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
                                ActivityLayout.setTranslationX(slideOffset * drawerView.getWidth());
                            }
                        };
drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();
```

Comment: Спасибоо !!!  все получилось )

Comment: Не за, что. Всегда пожалуйста.